# How redirect name without hyphen by htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I'm having problems removing the hyphen from my friendly url, after I updated apache it seems that it stopped working

my url would be
[www.mydomain.com/sales/super-cumputer](http://www.mydomain.com/sales/super-cumputer)

need to get super-cumputer without "-"

//would not want to use PHP to remove
`$name_computer = $_GET['name_computer'];`

need this in $1
//super computer

my redirect is like this currently

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\-
RewriteRule ^sales/?([^/]*)?/?$ /my_products.php?name_computer=$1&new_page=1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: You could think of two groups with a possible `_` in the middle and match both to `name_computer=$1$2`. However, I would rather do this sort of thing within PHP itself and leave the server configuration as simple as possible.

Comment: I understand, but I already have a hundred pages like this, for me it would be simpler to manage not to send the hyphen to the get,
thanks for answering

Comment: I fail to see anything in that rule that attempts to handle a hyphen in the URL. Actually the contrary: the condition takes care that the rule only gets applied to requested URL that do NOT have a hyphen. In your question you write the "it stopped working" ... So _what_ stopped working? Where is that rule you apparently refer to?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your `RewriteCondition` is looking for URIs without a `-` in them, instead, you want it to look for one matching dashes.

Then, as I mentioned in the comment, you can add two separate groups to match.

```
RewriteRule ^sales/?([^-/]*)\-?([^-/]*)?/?$ /my_products.php?name_computer=$1%20$2&new_page=1 [L,QSA]
```

I personally wouldn't recommend this though as this is a very specific match and if you have a variable with two dashes to separate words (ie. `/sales/new-super-computer/`, this would not match. I would rather handle this type of logic within my application code.

Edit: This tool can help you test your rules
https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=77ed5323-9db5-4a63-a9df-7864b4fbb147